# Hie i am new to mongo db. I want add a new field to a single existing document. How can i achieve this using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend

For example i have document like this

```
{_id:1,
 name:"John"         
}
```

After adding new field it should be like this

```
 {_id:1,
 name:"John",
 last_name:"doe"         
}
```

Comment: Welcome, your question needs improvements so please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`updateOne`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) API with the `$set` [update operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/):

```
db.collection.updateOne({_id: 1}, {$set: {last_name: "doe"}});
```

You didn't mention which library you're using, so I cannot recommend a specific call, but I'd assume that something like this should usually be available.